# WSO2 APIM 4.1.0: multi-tenancy with custom OIDC identity provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, multi-tenant

I am using **WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0** and I am trying to configure it with a custom OAuth2 authenticator to provide different users to different tenants.

By following [this guide, meant for Okta](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/sso/okta-as-an-external-idp-using-oidc/), I was able to make logging in and token claim-to-role mapping work, with some adjustments to the configuration to adapt to the custom IdP. Users can successfully login with the custom IdP, are assigned roles correctly, and can act accordingly in the publisher and developer portals.

However, I cannot figure out if there is any way to assign users to any tenant other than *carbon.super*.

The custom IdP I am working with uses e-mail addresses as usernames and, when `enable_email_domain=true` in the configuration file *deployment.toml*, users are created in APIM with said e-mail as their names, but if that setting is `false` (or commented), only the part before *@* is used. I thought this could be used to assign them to other tenants, but even if the e-mail domain is an existing tenant, the user is created in *carbon.super*.

I've noticed, when logging into *carbon* as admin, in the *Service Providers* section, under *Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration* for *apim_devportal* and *apim_publisher*, the *Use tenant domain in local subject identifier* setting. I am unsure what exactly this option entails, but checking it does not seem to change anything.

[This article](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/multitenancy/managing-tenants/) in the documentation talks about tenants, but does not cover this scenario.

Does anyone know how (if it's even possible) to assign a user to a specific API Manager tenant, instead of *carbon.super*, upon logging in via custom IdP (not Okta or Identity Server)?

Answer (score 0):

same question here, i use Keycloak as Idp and not found solutions yet for multitenancy schema implementation

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).